# Laravel global variable for base layout

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-5

I have a few things that I want to present on every page, like `$gameAccounts = Auth::user()->gameAccounts()->get();`

What would be the best approach to present this variable globally, on each page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it only for the views you can use a view composer in your `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('layouts.base', function ($view) {
        $view->with('gameAccounts', Auth::user()->gameAccounts);
    });
}
```

If you need it globally you can store it in a config also in `AppServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

For shared functionality I would recommend to write a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). The trait can be used throughout your controllers and provide the same functionality for all.

**Example:**

```
trait GameSettingsTrait 
{
    public function getUserGameAccounts()
    {
        return Auth::user()->gameAccounts()->get();
    }
}
```

In your controller do:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    use GameSettingsTrait;

    ...
```

**Another approach** would be to put the logic in the base controller in `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`. Btw, there you can see that it already uses traits for other functionality.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to access that variable through the base layout, so that I can use it in every view I have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use view composer.

Look at the doc.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

Use view composer is a best way to do this.
Just add this rows to your AppServiceProvider.php inside boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    //

    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
        $view->with('user', Auth::user()->gameAccounts()->get());
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't use `'*'`, every view will run `Auth::user()->gameAccounts()->get()`. You have to specify the base layout/template view instead.